# increase Left property dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made image slider in which images are placed by calculating

```
image.pc = my.percentLandscape;
image.style.left =  xs - (image.pc / 2) / z * my.size +'px';
```

I want to increase the Gap between images [image]. how to dynamically calculate value for left property.

I am using imageFlow http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Introduction

Comment: Surely adding a constant to your existing calculation would do it?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray tried adding constant value. only gap between 2nd and 3rd image is increased

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your current calculation in detail (what does xs represent for example) and provide better examples of your code...

Comment: @ChrisMoutray i have used imageFlow code and have made all desired changes.                                                       var z = (Math.sqrt(10000 + x * x) + 100) * my.imagesM;
var xs = x / z * my.size + my.size;

Comment: looking at the examples http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Examples the **xStep** attribute seems add a gap

Comment: possible duplicate of [imageFlow Left property to increase Gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537594/imageflow-left-property-to-increase-gap)

Comment: hey, would you mind showing your js properties? mine looks very different from your

Answer (score 2):

<strike>have you tried modifying the css?</strike>

```
.imageflow img { margin: 0 50px;}
```

This seems to worked when i tried to modify the css directly on that website

EDIT

Sorry my solution above was wrong, I downloaded the plug-in and looked in details.
Because each images are absolute position and position is dynamically calculated, you have to modify the javascript to have more spaces.

If you have your site uploaded somewhere, then i can look into more details but from the sample you can download from the web site, you can edit following code in the javascript

file: imageflow.js

```
line: 583: image.style.left = xs - (image.pc / 2) / z * my.size + (50 * index) + 'px';
```

I've added

```
(50 * index)
```

so it will have 50 more pixels between each images.

**EDIT 2**

because of the changes i made in my first Edit, it has shifted all the image to the right.
It just need re-calculate the displayed index vs hidden index.

in line 543, i added following line

```
/* Main loop */
var firstImageIndex = -1;   <---------------------------------this one
for (var index = 0; index < my.max; index++)
```

Then in line 560, added following line

```
else
{
   if (firstImageIndex < 0)  <---------------------------------this line
      firstImageIndex = index; <-------------------------------this line

   var z = (Math.sqrt(10000 + x * x) + 100) * (my.imagesM + 5);
   var xs = x / z * my.size + my.size;
```

Then on the line we edited in Edit 1, change the logic to following

```
image.style.left = xs - (image.pc / 2) / z * (my.size - 50) + (10 * (index - firstImageIndex)) + 'px';
```

Let me know if this is too confusing, or doesn't work, i'll send you the javascript that i edited.

Good luck

**Edit 3**
I've made few modification, location of these codes are same as the Edit 2 area.

```
First section
    /* Main loop */
    var firstImageIndex = -1;
    var scaleLevel = 5; // higher the number, it will scale it smaller
    var extraSpaceBetweenImage = 100; //extra Space Between Images measured by px
    var shiftLeftLevel = 4; // shift the for image element to the left,
```

2nd section

```
if (firstImageIndex < 0)
     firstImageIndex = index;

var z = (Math.sqrt(10000 + x * x) + 100) * (my.imagesM + scaleLevel);
```

3rd section

```
image.style.left = xs - (image.pc / 2) / z * (my.size - 50) + (extraSpaceBetweenImage * (index - firstImageIndex - shiftLeftLevel)) + 'px';
```

Comment: i tried adding this in my css but it doesnt work . where didi you try modifying ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I re-looked at the project and my solution above was wrong, I'll edit the solution above.

Comment: great work,you made my day thanks a lot .. i just want to know how did u calculate? i spend 2 days calculating this...

Comment: i just used firebug and see whats changing in the each animation, in this case css property of "left" was changing to set the position. so then i went into the javascript and search for ".left"

Comment: i knew that left property need to be change but how did you made changes in formula?? 50 * index   this ???  because i tried adding variavles but nothing worked for me

Comment: hey you noticed that it has moved very first image to right side , how to bring it in left ?

Comment: oooh I've written these kinda animation alot so I just knew what needed to be done. first image, add 0px, 2nd image add 50px, third image add 100px, so on. and to do this, you need some kind of counter, and i just saw index in the variable so i thought i can use that as counter. Just experience i think

Comment: help me to move First image to left ? because it has moved to right not because of margin but i guess because of calculation

Comment: with this  sliding functionality is getting disturb :(

Comment: haha yeaa this is the hard part, cause it kinda pushed everything to the right now. Let me update my solution above

Comment: First of All thanks for Efforts , and i did try EDIT2 but it's placing image same as it was displaying to very first without any changes .  images are still overlapping each other.

Comment: I'm sure you already got solution to this but just curious, have you tried modifying the xStep property? to around 250?

Comment: no i didnt get the solution ... modifying xstep will only increase gap for center  image .. i need ur js file which you updated

Comment: I've updated the code again, can you have a look? i've added properties at the top so you can easily change them and ajust the spacing and scaling

Answer (score -1):

```
image.pc = my.percentLandscape;
image.style.left = (( (xs - (image.pc / 2)) / z) * my.size )+'px';
```

Assuming xs, image.pc, z, and my.size is number

Answer (score -1):

You can do this, why setting image `left` and `right` margins.

Add margin in the following CSS class:

```
.imageflow img {
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px; // Add this line in your CSS
}
```

Comment: Try setting margins for every image.