# imageFlow Left property to increase Gap

Tags: jquery, css, imageflow

Has anyone here worked with http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/?

I want to increase gap between images, I've played with the settings but couldn't get it to work. I want the images not to overlap each other.

How do I do this?